# LCD screen back light not working

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop, lcd, backlight

Short story: The screen back light of my [Lenovo IdeaPad 700-15ISK-88IP7000671](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/search?query=Ideapad%20Y700) failed (the LCD works). I changed the LCD cable and then the whole LCD,without success.

Long story: My laptop LCD started to flicker, so I bought a new LCD. When I changed it, it worked fine, but accidentally disconnected the LCD cable. Then I tried to connect it again WITHOUT TURNING OFF COMPUTER; the LCD cable sparked at the connector, and the back light stopped working. After that I bought new LCD cable, changed it, but the problem haven't fixed. So I bought a new LCD, changed it, but the back light is still not working.

All in all: the back light is not working on 3 LCDs and 2 LCD cables. What's the problem?

Comment: Please look underneath your Y700 and find the serial number plate or sticker. Then, on that, find the model number, for there are five different classes of Y700 Ideapad, and many versions of each of those. Click on [edit].and put the model number in when you have it.

Comment: okay, i already did that

Answer (score 0):

The power to drive the LCD panel might have gone through components it shouldn't have, due to a short-circuit when you tried to connect your screen while turned on.

I would probably run down some of the pcb traces from the motherboard connector, and you might find burnt components/solder areas or a blown fuse. They aren't necessarily easy to find.

Overall, I don't have much hope for your laptop motherboard. You might need to send it to a repair shop if you don't feel confident replacing the components yourself.